# Jquery ui autocomplete change functionality on textbox refocus

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

Currently I am using a Jquery ui autocomplete, and after someone selects an option from a Jquery ui autocomplete, I am removing the focus from the textbox.

I would like to add the following functionality -
When someone clicks into the textbox again, I would like to leave the option that was previously selected in the text box, but highlight it (as if the text was double clicked), and redisplay all the choices.

How can this be done?

CURRENT CODE -

```
    $(function () {
        var availableItems = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
        $("#myTextBox").autocomplete({
            source: availableItems,
            minLength: 0,
            select: function(event, ui) { 
                $('#myTextBox').blur();
                }
        }).focus(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search");
        }); ;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put

```
$(this).select();
```

in the focus function()?

Also try

```
$(this).autocomplete("search", "");
```

to enhance an empty search